# Make intellij use gradle as build tool

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am using gradle to build my java project in Intellij.
I have also set this flag to true:
*Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment-> Build Tools-> Gradle-> Runner-> Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle*

Still, when I run gradle assemble, I see a '**build**' directory being created and when I run the build through intellij(Hammer icon), it creates a new directory called '**out**'.

I am not sure if this the expected behavior but I wanted to know if there is a way to have only the 'build' folder.

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample gradle project?

Comment: What version of IntelliJ?

Comment: @y.bedrov - it's not reproducible with new sample gradle project

Comment: @tim_yates - 2019.1.4

Comment: Please try to remove all IDE related data (.iml file and .idea folder) and reimport project from gradle build file.

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I still have this issue in 2022.2.3 I can compile and run my project from gradle-cli but the ide gives my a compile-time error.